# Find time period for a type of alarm with overlaps in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset (DATA) like this-

```
Store   Start                End                    Type   
XXXX    02-03-2015 10:04:00  02-03-2015 10:08:00    1  
XXXX    02-03-2015 10:06:00  02-03-2015 10:10:00    2  
XXXX    02-03-2015 10:09:30  02-03-2015 10:12:00    1  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:04:00  03-03-2015 20:12:00    1  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:06:00  03-03-2015 20:10:00    2  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:09:00  03-03-2015 20:16:00    1  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:15:00  03-03-2015 20:18:00    2  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:17:00  03-03-2015 20:22:00    2  
YYYY    03-03-2015 20:21:00  03-03-2015 20:27:00    1
```

The output of this file (RESULT) is-

```
Store   Start                End                  Mins of Type 2 only  
XXXX    02-03-2015 10:04:00  02-03-2015 10:12:00  00:01:30  
YYYY    02-03-2015 20:04:00  02-03-2015 20:27:00  00:05:00
```

So for each Store (Store is unique in the table), I am rolling up the intervals with overlaps to create a single interval.

Now, for each `store`, I want to find the time period for purely type `2`. So if there is an overlap, type `1` has the dominance. And I want the sum of time period of whatever is left for type `2`.

I have written this code but not able to address the overlap issue:

```
alter table [DATA] add Outage float;

update [DATA]
set Outage = DATEDIFF(SECOND,[Start],[END])

alter table [RESULT] add [Outage_Type1 (%)] float,[Outage_Type2 (%)] float;

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type1 (%)]=(Select (DATEDIFF(SECOND,Min([Start]),Max([END]))) from [DATA] where ([DATA].[Type]= '1') and ([RESULT].[Site_ID] = [DATA].[Site_ID]) and ([DATA].[Start] between [RESULT].[Start] and [RESULT].[End]) and ([DATA].[END] between [RESULT].[Start] and [RESULT].[End]))
 from [RESULT]

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type2 (%)]=(Select (DATEDIFF(SECOND,Min([Start]),Max([END]))) from [DATA] where ([DATA].[Type]= '2') and ([RESULT].[Site_ID] = [DATA].[Site_ID]) and ([DATA].[Start] between [RESULT].[Start] and [RESULT].[End]) and ([DATA].[END] between [RESULT].[Start] and [RESULT].[End]))
from [RESULT]

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type1 (%)]=0 where [Outage_Type1 (%)] is null;

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type2 (%)]=0 where [Outage_Type2 (%)] is null;

alter table [RESULT] add Outage float;

update [RESULT]
set Outage = DATEDIFF(SECOND,[Start],[END])

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type1 (%)]=Case when [Outage_Type1 (%)]<>0 then ([Outage_Type1 (%)]*100/Outage) 
            when [Outage_Type1 (%)]=0 then 0 End;

UPDATE [RESULT]
SET [Outage_Type2 (%)]=Case when [Outage_Type2 (%)]<>0 then ([Outage_Type2 (%)]*100/Outage) 
            when [Outage_Type2 (%)]=0 then 0 End;

alter table [RESULT] drop column outage;
```

Comment: These two sentences are contradicting "Now, for each store, I want to find the time period for purely type 2. So if there is an overlap, type 1 has the dominance." Which one is it? Purely Type 2 or Type 2 but Type 1 if it is more/less?

Comment: I read that sentence to mean, he wants the sum of time where only a type 2 is in effect.   When both type 1 & 2 are in effect, he doesn't want that time included in the sum of time.

Comment: Sorry for being contradicting. I want to remove the time interval where type 1 is in effect and just take the interval where only type 2 is in effect. For that reason, I have included the field, "Mins of Type 2 only" in my Result dataset.

Comment: I only want the sum of time for each store where only Type 2 is present.